# Why Eclipse give me errors on the break statments of this switch case structure?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have created this **switch case** structure in a Java program but Eclipse sign me errors on all the **break** statments:

```
public class LoadPlacesService {

    public String getPlaces(String source, String selval) {

        switch(source) {

        case "country":

            if (selval.equals("italy")) {
                return "<option value='marche'>Marche</option>\n<option value='lazio'>Lazio</option>\n<option value='lombardia'>Lombardia</option>\n<option value='puglia'>Puglia</option>";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }

        break;

        case "region":

            if (selval.equals("lazio")) {
                return "<option value='roma'>Roma</option>\n<option value='viterbo'>Viterbo</option>\n<option value='latina'>Latina</option>\n<option value='rieti'>Rieti</option>\n<option value='frosinone'>Frosinone</option>";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }

        break;

        // eventuali altri case

        case "district": 

            if (selval.equals("roma")) {
                return "<option value='roma'>Roma</option>\n<option value='guidonia-montecelio'>Guidonia Montecelio</option>\n<option value='fiumicino'>Fiumicino</option>\n<option value='aprilia'>Aprilia</option>";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }

        break;


    }
        return "";

    }

}
```

Comment: If both the `if` and the `else` have `return` statements, all paths terminate. Code execution will never reach the `break`. Please include the error next time.

Comment: Its because of your 'return', your 'break' becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Break is after the return. Return statement makes the code unreachable after that. Please remove break or remove return.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are unreachable due to the returns before

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are returning from your `else` clause in each `case` clause. That is making `break;` statement unreachable.

```
        } else {
            return "0";  // cause of the problem
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break` statement from all cases. Its not required since you are returning from all cases